# In Swift, do class pointers always point to the parent?

Tags: swift

```
let x = User()?
y = x 
z = y
```

Reference count for "x" should be 2, is that right?

```
y =  nil
```

Does `z` become nil, or does it continue to be a `User`?

Comment: What is `User()?`? Why isn't it just `User()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reference count for "x" should be 2, is that right?

Yes, you are passing around references, and you did that twice.

> Does `z` become nil, or does it continue to be `User`?

No, `z` does not become nil, since `z` holds a reference to the `User`. When `y` is set to nil, the reference count drops to 1, so it stays alive.

Answer (score 1):

`z` **does not** become nil. It maintains a reference to the (same) User object, which keeps the object alive.

For more information about object lifecycle and strong/weak references, see the [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) section of The Swift Programming Language.